# Magento collection - How can we add procedure function in WHERE condition

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, zend-db

I have a procedure in database: soundex_match_all

I want to add in Magento code where condition.

eg. WHERE `soundex_match_all('toys', product_name, ' ')=1`

Code:

```
$storeId  = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->setStoreId($storeId)
->addStoreFilter($storeId)
->addFieldToFilter("status",1)
->addFieldToFilter($attribute,array('like'=> '%'.$keyword.'%'))
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a JOIN statement? Your code gets converted to SQL by the framework I reckon.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, i don't want JOIN statement. I want to use my DB procedure in Magento code.

Comment: Oooh, I misread then. I interpreted it as you wanted to put Magento code in a where statement but now I see you probably want to use the equivalent of SQL WHERE in your getCollection()(?) statement.

Answer (score 1):

you can add a custom where statement to collection sql

```
$products->getSelect()->where("soundex_match_all('toys', product_name, ' ') = 1");
```

beware of using table prefixes when using fieldnames.
Make sure your sql is correct with

```
$products->getSelect()->__toString();
```

also take a look at methods `orWhere()` and `andWhere()` to combine your filter expressions